# DescTools :: AUC() trapezoid returns completely different results for na.rm = T and F in a dataset without NA

Tags: r, auc, na.rm

I have a dataset (**alldata**) with a time variable for X in hours (**Time**) and a numeric measurement for Y (**Value**) for a number of patients with a certain **PID** (**allPID** = vector with all PIDs).
For the first 24 hours, I want to calculate the area under the curve. First, I used the following script:

```
AUC1 <- as.data.frame(allPID)
for(i in allPID) {
  x <- alldata[alldata$PID == i & alldata$Time <= 24, "Time"]
  y <- alldata[alldata$PID == i & alldata$Time <= 24, "Value"]
  AUC1$AUC24trap[AUC1$allPID == i] <- AUC(x, y, 
                                          method = "trapezoid",
                                          na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

However, this script only provided an **AUC for 17 of 46 cases.**
Although I am not completely sure what the exact problem was with this script, the solution seemed to be to first bind x and y in a **dataframe** and use only **complete cases**.

```
AUC2 <- as.data.frame(allPID)
for(i in allPID) {
  x24 <- alldata[alldata$PID == i & alldata$Time <= 24, "Time"]
  y24 <- alldata[alldata$PID == i & alldata$Time <= 24, "Value"]
  df24 <- cbind(x24,y24)
  df24 <- as.data.frame(df24[complete.cases(df24), ])
  AUC2$AUC24[AUC2$allPID == i] <- AUC(df24$x24, df24$y24, 
                                          method = "trapezoid", na.rm = T
)
}
```

I figured that since I use **'complete.cases'** (and there are indeed no NAs in the df24), I could set **na.rm = F**. **BUT: this provides completely different results than if I use na.rm = T.**

Leaving the question: *why are these results so different? What is is that the na.rm does in this case?*

Hopefully someone can help out!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the NA-handling of AUC(). It has been fixed in DescTools 0.99.44.